# Montar consulta para cenário específico

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com o modelo abaixo (dados consistentes):

```
CODIGO | INICIO | FIM
     1 |   2018 | NULL
     1 |   2017 | 2017
     1 |   2014 | 2016
```

Preciso encontrar os registros onde o `INICIO` tem o mesmo valor do `FIM` anterior, como abaixo, onde os dados das linhas 1 e 2 são inconsistentes:

```
CODIGO | INICIO | FIM
     1 |   2018 | NULL
     1 |   2017 | 2018
     1 |   2014 | 2016
```

Tentei com a query abaixo mas não sei o que está errado...

```
SELECT T.CODIGO, T.INICIO, T.FIM, X.*
FROM TABELA T
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT T1.CODIGO, T1.INICIO, T1.FIM
                FROM TABELA T1
                WHERE T1.CODIGO = T.CODIGO
                AND T1.INICIO = T.FIM    
) X
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Preciso encontrar os registros onde o INICIO tem o mesmo valor do FIM anterior*

Avalie a seguinte sugestão:

```
-- código #1
SELECT T1.CODIGO, T1.INICIO, T1.FIM, 
       T2.INICIO as [INICIO L2], T2.FIM as [FIM L2]
  from TABELA as T1
       inner join TABELA as T2 on T2.CODIGO = T1.CODIGO
                                  and T2.INICIO = T1.FIM;
```